# Issues running Powershell Get-ADComputer in a loop

Tags: loops, powershell

This is driving me crazy. I'm a beginner at Powershell, but I can't see what's wrong here.

I'm basically running a script which goes off and checks the description field in AD, looks for a match for the user input and pulls back the PC name and the associated description. As below:

```
import-module activedirectory

$User = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter User's First OR Surname OR partial String"
$User = '*' + $User + '*'
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Description -like $User' -Properties Description | Select Name, Description
write-Host "================================================================="
}
```

This on it's own works fine. However I want to loop this until it is closed, so the user can do another search straight away. When I put this into a loops, the first time the search is ran, no results are returned. The 2nd time the first lot of results are returned with the 2nd lot. From then on it works as normal.

So the output looks something like:

```
Enter User's First OR Surname OR partial String: Test

=================================================================
Enter User's First OR Surname OR partial String: Test
Name      Description                
----      -----------                
COMPXXX01 Test, PS 
COMPXXX01 Test, PS   

=================================================================
```

So essentially the first lot of results come through on the second run.

I've tried a few ways of looping for example:

```
import-module activedirectory

While($true)
{
$User = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter User's First OR Surname OR partial String"
$User = '*' + $User + '*'
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Description -like $User' -Properties Description | Select Name, Description
write-Host "================================================================="
}
```

Any advice would be greatly received.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow take a tour Go through [How to Ask on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which helps you for more views and some Answers

Comment: `$filter = "Description -like $User"`, then `Get-ADComputer -Filter $filter`?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting find. As far as I can tell there is some sort of bug with the console & Get-ADComputer. The Get-Adcomputer does "work" in getting the info (**put in a variable and the contents show there**) but will **not output**. Funny if you put the output twice it will work the 2nd time:

```
While($true)
{
    $User = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter User's First OR Surname OR partial String"
    $User = '*' + $User + '*'
    Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Description -like $User' -Properties Description | Select Name, Description
    Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Description -like $User' -Properties Description | Select Name, Description
    write-Host "================================================================="
}
```

A work around would be to have a flag for the 1st time:

```
$firstTime = $true

While($true)
{
    $User = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter User's First OR Surname OR partial String"
    $User = '*' + $User + '*'
    $computerTable = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Description -like $User' -Properties Description | Select Name, Description    

    if($firstTime){
        $firstTime = $false           
        $computerTable 
    }

    $computerTable

    write-Host "================================================================="
}
```

Comment: OK great, I'm glad it's not just me who is see this behaviour. Thanks for your workaround. I'll give that a go.

Comment: These seems pretty weird but "should have" worked. I've tried various things (using for loop, foreach, write-output). Only thing that I've gotten to work is if in the "Select" portion if you use "-extendproperty name", it will work but only return the "name" (no desc). The cmdlet is returning only a "string" with that "-extendproperty" and not an object. So the bug seems to be in the return "object" part of the cmdlet. Curios if an update broke this.

Comment: When I enter a vague search with a couple of characters which would produce a number of results, the script works as expected first time. However if I'm too specific and run a search with one or two results, it doenst work first time. Maybe its just not allowing enough time for the AD cmdlet to run? Any ideas?

Comment: One final follow up, if I add "| format-table" onto the end of my Get statement, it works fine. Go figure.

Comment: Appears to be a timing bug of sorts with the console but if that is the case I think format-table (write-host works as well but the format is not desirable) is your best best as you are using the info for console display and if you needed it for other uses/output the data/variable still works.